# How to overlay a parametric curve on a vector field plot?

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to overlay parametrized curves on two-dimensional vector plots?

For example, I'd like to be able to overlay circles

$$\mathbf{c}(t)=\langle R\cos t+h, R\sin t+k\rangle$$

(for specific values of $R, h, k$) on

```
VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

In fact, I'd really like to be able to overlay the circles as well as their tangent and normal vector fields, shown in a different color than the underlying field.

The documentation doesn't give examples of this sort. Perhaps it could be done by using a second field for which the circle I desire to plot is a streamline?

Comment: `ParametricPlot` and `Show` is one way.

Comment: `Show[Graphics[Circle[]], VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]]`

Comment: `VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Epilog -> 
  ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[
     Join @@ Table[{r Cos[t] + h, r Sin[t] + k}, {r, 1, 4, 1}, {k, -1,
         1, 1}, {h, -1, 1, 1}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}][[1]]]`?

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions; I didn't know `Show`. `Show[ParametricPlot[ {Cos[t] - 1, Sin[t] - 1}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}], 
 VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` gives a nice solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Epilog -> ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t]+h, r Sin[t] + k}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle->Red][[1]]],
  {{r, 2, "r"}, 1, 4}, {{h, 0, "h"}, -1, 1}, {{k, 0, "k"}, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Terrific -- you read my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @symplectomorphic, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.